JSX showing tag is not define
I am creating element using JSX but it is showing me the error
***ERROR***
script.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: h2 is not defined
    at 6rimH.react (script.js:13:14)
    at newRequire (index.8cfc62b9.js:71:24)
    at index.8cfc62b9.js:122:5
    at index.8cfc62b9.js:145:3
6rimH.react @   script.js:13
newRequire  @   index.8cfc62b9.js:71
(anonymous) @   index.8cfc62b9.js:122
(anonymous) @   index.8cfc62b9.js:145

***Here is my script file ***
Here React element creating is working but Not JSX.
unable to create and render the title element using JSX. Getting and error showing
** h2 is not defined**
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

const heading = React.createElement(
  "h1",
  { id: "reactEl" },
  "Hello welcome to React"
);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"));
root.render(heading);
console.log(heading);

let title = <h2>Hello World welcome to JSX</h2>;

root.render(title);

Here React element creating is working but Not JSX.

Try to rename file from js to jsx
